# Transform String to Integer Ansible

Tags: ubuntu, ansible, yaml

I need to convert a string "1933" to `integer` in Ansible PB.

Code:

```
- set_fact:
    parent_region2: "1933"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ parent_region2 | int }}"
```

Expected Output:
`"msg": 1933`

Actual Output:
`"msg": "1933"`

Though the Actual Output have braces, it still shows as int when passing a `type_debug` into the code

Code with `type_debug`:

```
- set_fact:
    parent_region2: "1933"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ parent_region2 | int | type_debug}}"
```

Output:
`"msg": "int"`

Please help

Answer (score 2):

It's an integer when *type_debug* tells you so. The quotes are not part of the integer, of course. The format of the output depends on the [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html). For example, the *default* callback plugin (see `ansible-doc -t callback default`) gives JSON by default

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=default ansible-playbook test.yml

ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "1933"
}
```

and the *yaml* callback plugin (see `ansible-doc -t callback yaml`) gives single-quoted YAML

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=yaml ansible-playbook test.yml

ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: '1933'
```

If you want to be sure write a filter e.g.

```py
shell> cat filter_plugins/python_type.py
def python_type(s):
    return type(s)

class FilterModule(object):
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'python_type': python_type,
        }
```

Then the tasks

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parent_region2|python_type }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ parent_region2|int|python_type }}"
```

should give

```yaml
  msg: <class 'ansible.parsing.yaml.objects.AnsibleUnicode'>
  msg: <class 'int'>
```

---

Q: **"*Won't Jinja2 just cast it to the string after evaluating the template?*"**

A: Yes, the output of the Jinja template is a string. It's up to you how you format the output. For example, given the template

```yaml
shell> cat test.txt.j2
{{ parent_region2|type_debug }} {{ parent_region2 }}
{{ parent_region2|int|type_debug }} {{ parent_region2|int }}
```

the task

```yaml
    - template:
        src: test.txt.j2
        dest: test.txt
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat test-094.txt
AnsibleUnicode 1933
int 1933
```

Comment: Won't jinja2 just cast it to string after evaluating the template?

Comment: @toydarian That's what I researched too. I was wondering, and still researching. if there is a way for jinja2 to cast it to integer instead of string. If you know a workaround, it would be a pleasure to hear it

Comment: Yes, the output of a template is a string. What else could it be? It's up to you how you format the template. I've added an example. It's an unfortunate situation that Ansible callback plugins format integers as strings. You can write your [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_plugins.html) if you want to.